Unable to replace the prefix in a Panda series
I am having a Panda series where I am calculating the max value out of it and then going to compare that max value with a specific value
But when I use df.max then I get the max value out of the Panda series but I also get the column name out of it
I tried using replace(), removeprefix() methods but no use.
Below is what I have tried :
df_speed=pd.DataFrame(df_ls['gSpeed'])
max_speed=df_speed.max()
temp=max_speed.replace('gSpeed','')

temp_speed=max_speed.to_string()
temp_speed.removeprefix('gSpeed')

logger.info(f'Max speed {max_speed}')
logger.info(f'temp speed {temp}')
logger.info(f'Return type {type(max_speed)} {type(temp_speed)} {type(temp_speed)}')

Below is the output I am getting:
Max speed gSpeed    303.549
dtype: float64
temp speed None
temp_speed {temp_speed}
Return type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> <class 'str'> <class 'str'>
Ideally it should remove the prefix:'gSpeed' and the extra space before it outputs the actual value: 303.549
Expected Output:
Max speed 303.549
temp speed 303.549
I would be also fine if we could remove the usage of temp and temp_speed variable.
I just want to remove the extra prefix and the space and just print the actual max value
Thanks!

I think if you use max() directly on Series, you should get only the value.
sample
gSpeed_series = pd.Series([120, 150, 303.549, 299, 280], name='gSpeed')

max_speed = gSpeed_series.max()

print("Max speed : \n")
print(max_speed)

Output
Max speed : 

303.549


When you run df.max(), it will return a value per column since it operates over axis=0 by default. Specifying axis=None will return the global max over the dataframe.
@rehaqds points out that in pandas versions prior to 2.0, axis=0 and axis=None are equivalent, so axis=None won't resolve your problem in that case. You could instead use df.max().max() for the global max, or alternatively df["gSpeed"].max() if you want the result for a specific column (as per the answer by @samhita).
I assume your dataframe looks similar to:
    gSpeed
0   10
1   20
2   30
3   40
4   50

Then you can get the maximum speed as a scalar using
max_speed = df_speed.max(axis=None)

Reproducible example
import pandas as pd

#Data for testing
df_speed = pd.DataFrame({'gSpeed': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})
display(df_speed)

#Solution
max_speed = df_speed.max(axis=None)

print('Maximum speed:', max_speed)

Output:
Maximum speed: 50


For Pandas version older than 2.0 where axis=None is the same as axis=0., there is another solution (that should work for any version if the DF has only one column):   df_speed.max().max()

Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.
